# timestamp problem in android sqlite3

Tags: android

I want insert the current date and time into my table....
I used this query

```
insert into tbl_reminder values("Description",current_timestamp);
```

but it insert the wrong time...
actually the timestamp in my emulator is `2010-09-16 18:40:06`
but the inserted timestamp value is `2010-09-16 13:10:06`
what i do to insert the exact time...

Comment: How do you get your `current_timestamp`?

Comment: current_timestamp is a default keyword to insert the current time in database...so i didn't give any value for that...

Answer (score 1):

Insert it enclosed within Quotes, the date will be stored as a string.

`sqlite` doesn't has a `Date` datatype.

*Now, the following is just incase you are planning to use the `Date` column for Comparisions...*

Speaking from experience, i would advice you store it as Long Integer, as a Unix Timestamp, it lets you do Comparison between dates, which would otherwise be very difficult.

You'll obviously have to convert it to-and-fro but in the long run it's a better stratergy.